# Lua and object spawning

Tags: oop, lua

My gut tells me that I'm making an obvious mistake, but it's escaping me. I'm attempting to make 'child' objects from a specified 'parent' object by use of the following example code.

```
local Ad = {
    __index = Ad,
    __tostring = function(self) return self.msg end,
    __concat = function(a, b) return tostring(a)..tostring(b) end,
    Initialize = function(self, msg, wgt)
        if msg and msg ~= "" then
            wgt = wgt or 1
            self.msg, self.wgt, self.ranLog = msg, wgt, {}
        end
    end,
    Increase = function(self)
        if self.wgt < 9 then self.wgt = self.wgt + 1 end
    end,
    Decrease = function(self)
        if self.wgt > 1 then self.wgt = self.wgt - 1 end
    end
}

local function new(src, ...)
    local o = setmetatable({}, src)
    if src.Initialize then o:Initialize(...) end
    return o
end

local ad = new(Ad, "Test Message")
print("Object - "..ad)
for k, v in pairs(ad) do print("", k, v) end
ad:Increase()
print("Modified Object - "..ad)
for k, v in pairs(ad) do print("", k, v) end
```

So that's verbatim what fails with an attempt to call method Initialize which is a nil value. Given that before this edit my sample code did work, is it a matter of how table Ad has been defined? Or do I have a syntax error in here somewhere?

- edited to replace code snippit with actual code that fails

Comment: When I replace your comments with real code, this works for me. I think you simplified your code too much.

Comment: ok, here's (except for variable names that I'm leaving as example) more of my tables in case this is the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
local Ad = {
    __index = Ad,
    ...
}
```

At the time `__index` is assigned, `Ad` is `nil`, because the table is constructed in full before being assigned to `Ad`. Since `__index` is unset, the lookup for `Initialize` fails.

Instead, do something like:

```
local Ad = {
    ...
}
Ad.__index = Ad
```

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, `Ad` is not in scope yet in that table constructor so when you do `_index = Ad` its actually using the global variable `Ad`. This also evaluates to nil by default so it works the same but it means you can catch these mistakes by changing the metatable for the global environment (strict mode) or by using a linter.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. `Ad` will cause an access to `_G.Ad`, which is `nil`. That is a good point though. Had a global `Ad` existed then it would have been assigned to `__index`, which is even more unexpected behaviour. Care should always be taken when playing in metatables!